Batch file to export a file list of files bigger than 100 MB and older than 2019?
I want to write a batch file to search files in a drive that bigger than 100 MB and older than 2019/1/1, and then export the result (included detail path to sub-folder) as list (txt or csv)
I tried list and find command but filed, any hints can help me ?
Thanks

Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].
